# iOS framework XLPagerTabStrip not working properly

Tags: ios, swift, xlpagertabstrip

I am using `XLPagerTabStrip` for getting `TabBar` with `ViewPager` type behaviour like Android. I have configured as per their github repo documentation guideline but on my case it is having a peculiar behaviour at my simulator iPhone11 Pro max and real device iPhone 6+. The tab bar is scrolling a bit on selecting last tab though there is no need of scroll. And in iPhone 6, It is showing full screen for single tab. I am attaching code and screenshot. Any kind of help is appreciable.  Thanks in advance
**Here is my code**

```
class TalkRoomPagerViewController: BaseButtonBarPagerTabStripViewController<PagerTabCell>, StoryboardBased, ViewModelBased {

    var viewModel: TalkRoomPagerViewModel!
    private let bag = DisposeBag()

    private var allTalkRoom: TalkRoomListViewController {
        let viewModel = TalkRoomListViewModel(type: .all,
                                              filteredTalkroomWithPreferenceLists: self.viewModel.allTalkRoomWithPreferenceLists,
                                              requestPreferenceUpdate: self.viewModel.requestPreferenceUpdate,
                                              pagerTabIndex: self.viewModel.pagerTabIndexSubject.asObserver())
        let services = TalkroomListServices(chatRoomNetwork: ChatRoomNetwork())
        let viewController = TalkRoomListViewController.instantiate(withViewModel: viewModel, andServices: services)
        return viewController
    }
    private var siteTalkRoom: TalkRoomListViewController {
        let viewModel = TalkRoomListViewModel(type: .site,
                                              filteredTalkroomWithPreferenceLists: self.viewModel.siteTalkRoomWithPreferenceLists,
                                              requestPreferenceUpdate: self.viewModel.requestPreferenceUpdate)
        let services = TalkroomListServices(chatRoomNetwork: ChatRoomNetwork())
        let viewController = TalkRoomListViewController.instantiate(withViewModel: viewModel, andServices: services)
        return viewController
    }
    private var companyTalkRoom: TalkRoomListViewController {
        let viewModel = TalkRoomListViewModel(type: .company,
                                              filteredTalkroomWithPreferenceLists: self.viewModel.companyTalkRoomWithPreferenceLists,
                                              requestPreferenceUpdate: self.viewModel.requestPreferenceUpdate)
        let services = TalkroomListServices(chatRoomNetwork: ChatRoomNetwork())
        let viewController = TalkRoomListViewController.instantiate(withViewModel: viewModel, andServices: services)
        return viewController
    }
    private var groupTalkRoom: TalkRoomListViewController {
        let viewModel = TalkRoomListViewModel(type: .group,
                                              filteredTalkroomWithPreferenceLists: self.viewModel.groupTalkRoomWithPreferenceLists,
                                              requestPreferenceUpdate: self.viewModel.requestPreferenceUpdate)
        let services = TalkroomListServices(chatRoomNetwork: ChatRoomNetwork())
        let viewController = TalkRoomListViewController.instantiate(withViewModel: viewModel, andServices: services)
        return viewController
    }

    public var steppers: [Stepper] {
        return [viewModel, allTalkRoom.viewModel, siteTalkRoom.viewModel, companyTalkRoom.viewModel, groupTalkRoom.viewModel]
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.prepareUI()
        self.configureNavigationBar()
        super.viewDidLoad()
        bindViewModel()

    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        viewModel.requestTalkRoomList.onNext(())
        viewModel.requestPreferenceList.onNext(())
        viewModel.locationFilter.accept(PersistenceManager.shared.savedFilterLocation)
    }

    func bindViewModel() {
        viewModel.pagerTabIndexSubject.subscribe(onNext: { (index) in
            self.moveToViewController(at: index, animated: true)
        })
            .disposed(by: bag)

        viewModel.preferenceUpdateResponse.subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] _ in
            self?.viewModel.requestTalkRoomList.onNext(())
            self?.viewModel.requestPreferenceList.onNext(())
        })
            .disposed(by: bag)
    }

    private func prepareUI() {
        self.title = "トークルーム一覧"
        buttonBarView.isScrollEnabled = false
        buttonBarItemSpec = ButtonBarItemSpec.nibFile(nibName: "PagerTabCell", bundle: Bundle(for: PagerTabCell.self)) { _ in
            return self.view.frame.width/4
        }
        settings.style.buttonBarBackgroundColor = .white
        settings.style.buttonBarItemBackgroundColor = .white
        settings.style.selectedBarBackgroundColor = Asset.duskBlue.color
        settings.style.selectedBarHeight = 2.0
        settings.style.buttonBarMinimumLineSpacing = 0
        settings.style.buttonBarItemTitleColor = .black
        settings.style.buttonBarLeftContentInset = 0
        settings.style.buttonBarRightContentInset = 0

        changeCurrentIndexProgressive = { (oldCell: PagerTabCell?, newCell: PagerTabCell?, progressPercentage: CGFloat, changeCurrentIndex: Bool, animated: Bool) -> Void in
            guard changeCurrentIndex == true else { return }
            oldCell?.titleLabel.textColor = .black
            newCell?.titleLabel.textColor = Asset.duskBlue.color
        }
    }

    private func configureNavigationBar() {
        self.addBarItem(position: .left, title: "編集", target: self, action: #selector(editButtonTapped))
        self.addBarItem(position: .right, image: Asset.iconPlus.image, target: self, action: #selector(addButtonTapped))
    }

    @objc private func editButtonTapped() {

    }

    @objc private func addButtonTapped() {
        self.viewModel.navigateToCreateTalkRoom()
    }

    override func viewControllers(for pagerTabStripController: PagerTabStripViewController) -> [UIViewController] {
        return [allTalkRoom, siteTalkRoom, companyTalkRoom, groupTalkRoom ]
    }

    override func configure(cell: PagerTabCell, for indicatorInfo: IndicatorInfo) {
        cell.iconImageView.image = indicatorInfo.image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
        cell.titleLabel.text = indicatorInfo.title

    }

}
```

[image: iPhone 6 plus screenshot] [image: iPhone 11 Pro Max simulator , initial view][image: iPhone 11 , problematic scenario]

Comment: Did you modify the class ```BaseButtonBarPagerTabStripViewController```? Have you tried using the ```elasticIndicatorLimit```? It looks like this one will stop scrolling sideways when you're at the first or last tab.

Comment: i didn't modify BaseButtonBarPagerTabStripViewController, I just inherited it. I din't tried elasticIndicatorLimit. Can you please tell me where to find this elasticIndicatorLimit property??

Comment: How do i use this elasticIndicatorLimit ?? any example please ..

Comment: Check their github documentation [here](https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLPagerTabStrip). There is this property and it is explained how to use it.

Comment: It is also very strange how you inherit from their class. You have it like this ```BaseButtonBarPagerTabStripViewController<PagerTabCell>```, but it should be like this ```BaseButtonBarPagerTabStripViewController```

Answer (score 0):

1. I don't know what is an issue in your code but I had used [XLPagerTabStrip](https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLPagerTabStrip) & getting the same kind of problem. They have very little documentation. I download their demo example code from Github. I just copy-paste their view controller From storyboard & code. After that, I modify it as per my requirements.
2. If you are using Xcode 11 or above then check your App’s Light Mode & Dark-mode capability. If your app is fully in Light mode then provide dark mode support. 
   I hope this may be helpful to you.